# Weird answer edit

Tags: discussion

With respect to: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/217726/11684

I understand perfectly why the edit took place, but perhaps changing "Yes there is" with "no there isn't" is too much of a change from the original answer that a new answer might be called for.  Tempted to roll back and include my comment as an answer, starting with "It would be misguided to sample without conditioning.

Answer (score 4):

I made that particular edit because both the rest of that sentence and the rest of the answer overall made it clear that the author preferred digital over analog processing. It seemed to me that the author simply made a typo in the first part of the sentence, because it was completely at odds with everything else he wrote.

At this point, I would leave it up to him to make any further changes to that answer.